# Calendar App with CSV import

Tags: software-recommendation, calendar, csv

At the moment i'm trying to switch from Outlook to Apple Mail / Cal.app and
would like to know if anyone here has found a way to batch import Calendar events
consistently from CSV files.

The usual CSV -> Google -> iCal route is not what i'm looking for.

Maybe an alternative (calendar) app for the Mac?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an app/program I would recommend that you search the Mac App Store and try googling for one.
I've heard that Sunrise Calendar is good but I think you need to find one that works good for you.

Personally, I would pin the Google Calendar website in Safari "Top Sites".

Comment: Already did that. Can't import CSV into google cal either.

Comment: @m_br Which calendars are you wanting to use? What company/brand do they come from?

Comment: I am using google calendar to sync my events, iCal as the desktop software. what i want is a simple way to batch import events from the desktop